# Getting Hibernate Session Count from application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I created simple Java application to learn Spring and hibernate integration. I have done all the setup and application also working fine.

Everything works fine. But, I want to see how much sessions are currently my application using like open connections and closed hibernate connections.

In **Sessionfactory** classs we have **"getStatistics"** method used to retrieve hibernate statistics data but this is not helping me. It gives me also Zero. please find below pic.

[image]

I want to ensure my application, using single session for entire application operations or not.

So is there any way to find out or to get Spring+hibernate sessions count.

My hibernate configuration file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
    <property name="username" value="rocky" />
    <property name="password" value="rocky" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>orders.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>hibernate.show_sql</value>
                </key>
                <value>true</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>hibernate.dialect</value>
                </key>
                <value>org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>hibernate.query.factory_class</value>
                </key>
                <value>org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>connection.autocommit</value>
                </key>
                <value>true</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionProxy"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="target" ref="myServiceClass">
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="myServiceClass" class="myServiceClass">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code It seams that you have not enable staticstics of your session factory

**Step to unable session factory statics**

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactoryForApplication();
Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
stats.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
```

Taken from this **[article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19807.html)**

hope this will solve your problem..!

Comment: Every method of Statistics Object is returning zero, not useful.